# Resizing the Task View ribbon in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, desktop-customization, task-view

I'm making the transition from Win 8.1 to Win 11. Ever since XP I've had an old toolbar (a remnant of PowerDesk from the early 90's), which hid along the right screen margin, appeared when I passsed the cursor close to it and allowed me to switch between thirteen or more virtual vertically stacked desktops with a single click. In Win 11 the toolbar no longer functions stably and I haven't found a similar lightweight product. So I was forced to make do with Win 11's virtual desktops, which are ok, I guess, but too bulky for my purposes. I like to have 12-13 desktops visible simultaneously, but Microsoft only allows me 7-8. Hence, my question: Is there any way I can shrink the task view ribbon, so I don't need to scroll around endlessly for the windows I'm looking for.

I'd be very thankful if someone could help me with this!

Comment: Windows 11 at this point has done away with User Toolbars (natively) and Task Windows cannot be changed to more than what is allowed. So you will most likely have to adapt to what they offer. You can add more icons to the Up Arrow (system tray) which will remain hidden until you display them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my question was not really about toolbars and icons (and my old toolbar was not a User Toolbar, but 3rd party). My problem is that I'd like to reduce the size of the strip of **virtual desktop thumbnails** referred to in win-11 as the Task View, which is not a User Toolbar either, since the Toolbar's height can be changed (e.g. in StartAllBack), but not, it seems, the Task View's. Does there exist some trick that would reduce the size of these thumbnails and thus allow more of them to be visible simultaneously on my screen?